# Search bar with select box in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i use the code below to create a select box in javascript. The user selects the option and then clicks a button to filter items. Onclick myfunction() is triggered and redirects to the new url to show results.

**I would like to add a search bar also along with the select box. The user will select the category from the select box and then will use the search bar to write a word or a phrase to search in the category he will select from the select drop down box.Check the image to understand how i would like to modify it.I do not want to select any plugins.**

[image example search bar with select box](https://colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/colorlib-searchform-3.jpg)

```
  <?php
  
   // Parameters
//elmnt: This is the select box taken by functions like "getElementById" or any other way.
//value: This is the value which needs to be selected from the options of elmnt.

   echo "<br><br>Filter Banggood products by Product Category: ";
echo '<select id="apo">
<option value="0">All Products</option>
<option value="1">Smartphones</option>
    <option value="2">Projectors</option>
      <option value="3">Vaccum cleaner</option>
     
</select>';


echo "  ";
?>
<input type="button" value="Apply Filter" style="background-color:grey" onclick="myfunction('<?php echo $r1 ?>')"/>
<script>
    
 var noumero=<?php echo $r1
     ?>;
  
     if (noumero=="44")
     {
       document.getElementById('apo').value = '<?php echo "1" ?>';
     }
     else if (noumero=="38")
     {
       document.getElementById('apo').value = '<?php echo "2" ?>';
     }
      else if (noumero=="194")
     {
       document.getElementById('apo').value = '<?php echo "3" ?>';
     }
    
     else
     {
  document.getElementById('apo').value = '<?php echo "0" ?>';
     }
 </script>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a library like Semantic UI

Take a look at the labelled input here

[Semantic UI Labelled Input](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/input.html#labeled)